# Save information from MS crash reporter?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-error-reporting

On Windows XP when a process crashes, we get a dialog box with a link:

"To view technical information about the error report, click here."

The "click here" link brings up a whole lot of information in a window, but no obvious way to save it to a file. Is there a way? It would be very nice to be able to send that data to several different external vendors we're working with.

The only other option I see in the dialog box is to send it to Microsoft, but this crash is likely not Microsoft's fault and there is no reason to send it to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a company, you can register with Microsoft to be able to download WER reports.

Answer (score 1):

As of when you see this dialog box, you should still be able to manually attach a debugger (e.g. Visual Studio) to the crashing process and take a look at any available exception records.  Alternatively, I believe you should be able to register Visual Studio to handle these crashes instead of the normal error reporting mechanism.  This article seems to have more information about that option:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late for '08 question, but anyway, you may use [Error Report Grabber](http://www.maxerist.net/main/soft-for-win/err-rep-grabber) software for this task