# Can I get an error log after the user clicks: "check online for a solution and close the program" , and possibly reply with a fix?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, error-handling, crash

Some time the programs crash and display this generic error message:

> WindowsFormApplication1 has stopped working
>
> Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
>
> - *check online for a solution and close the program*
> - Close the program
> - Debug the program

what happen when the user click on "check online for a solution and close the program" ?

**My question specifically is:**

1. Can I get a log of crashes like this from clients that experience errors this way (through MS or directly) ?
2. Does Microsoft log those error somewhere so that I can check what errors did my application do ?
3. Can I submit to Microsoft or somewhere my fix for this error so that it notifies the users of a possible fix ?

Comment: I heard that they all get sent to [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Comment: @JasonSperske :))) - seriously - I think you shouldn't rely on MS to get you your errors, but should handle it yourself. The 'fix' point makes sense though, but I haven't heard about it. There're many ways to catch 'critical' exceptions (and at different levels) - what kind of problems, exceptions are you talking about. Have you tried something, failed etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an error report from a "Please tell Microsoft about this problem." dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709654/how-do-i-get-an-error-report-from-a-please-tell-microsoft-about-this-problem), [How To Get My Solutions Into Windows Problem Reports and Solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1816088), [Save information from MS crash reporter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/319334)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Get My Solutions Into Windows Problem Reports and Solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816088/how-to-get-my-solutions-into-windows-problem-reports-and-solutions)